# Has anyone integrated Backbone.Marionette and Rendr?

Tags: marionette

It looks like Backbone.Marionette views manipulate the DOM for events and such, so I'm guessing this is not as trivial as changing the base class references e.g. Backbone.View to BaseView.

Has anyone tackled this?  Is it feasible given the above?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if anyone has done it yet but there is interest in the github issue queue.

https://github.com/airbnb/rendr/issues/63